# Calculate histogram of gradients (HOG) of a fixed length regardless of image size

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I'm training a HOG + SVM model, and my training data comes in various sizes and aspect ratios. The SVM model can't be trained on variable sized lists, so I'm looking to calculate a histogram of gradients that is the same length regardless of image size.

Is there a clever way to do that? Or is it better to resize the images or pad them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What people usually do in such case is one of the follow two things:

1. Resize all images (or image patches) to a fixed size and extract the HOG features from those.
2. Use the "Bag of Words/Features" method and don't resize the images.

The first method `1.` is quite simple but it has some problems which method `2.` tries to solve.
First, think of what a hog descriptor does. It divides an image into cells of a fixed length, calculates the gradients cell-wise to generate cell-wise histograms(based on voting). At the end, you'll have a concatenated histogram of all the cells and that's your descriptor.

So there is a problem with it, because the object (that you want to detect) has to cover the images in similar manner. Otherwise your descriptor would look different depending on the location of the object inside the image.

Method `2.` works as follows:

1. Extract the HOG features from both positive and negative images in your training set.
2. Use an clustering algorithm like k-means to define a fixed amount of `k` centroids.
3. For each image in your dataset, extract the HOG features and compare them element-wise to the centroids to create a frequency histogram.

Use the frequency histograms for the training of your SVM and use it for the classification phase. This way, the location doesn't matter and you'll always have a fixed sized of inputs. You'll also benefit from the reduction of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the images to a given target shape using cv2.resize(), divide image into number of blocks you want and calculate the histogram of orientations along with the magnitudes. Below is a simple implementation of the same.

```
img = cv2.imread(filename,0)
img = cv2.resize(img,(16,16)) #resize the image

gx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0) #horizontal gradinets
gy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1) # vertical gradients

mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
bin_n = 16 # Number of bins
# quantizing binvalues in (0-16)
bins = np.int32(bin_n*ang/(2*np.pi))

# divide to 4 sub-squares
s = 8 #block size
bin_cells = bins[:s,:s],bins[s:,:s],bins[:s,s:],bins[s:,s:]
mag_cells = mag[:s,:s], mag[s:,:s], mag[:s,s:], mag[s:,s:]
hists = [np.bincount(b.ravel(), m.ravel(), bin_n) for b, m in zip(bin_cells,mag_cells)] 

hist = np.hstack(hists) #histogram feature data to be fed to SVM model
```

Hope that helps!